# How can I see a list of my ElasticSearch indices in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am starting to use ES and Kibana, so apologies in advance if this question doesn't make sense!

I'd like to be able to see in Kibana a list of my current indices, similar to what you get with:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

I was expecting to be able to see in Kibana functionality partly like a DB client where you can connect to a DB server and see all the databases, then drill down in each of them to see tables and content. I'd love to have that kind of workflow in Kibana.

The closest I can find is in Management -> Index Pattern, but it'll display a list of all fields, which is too much information and I can't see any column in the table that points to which index each field belongs.

As I said I'm just starting so it might be I'm not looking in the right place!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have any option to see the hierarchy like you see in traditional DB application.

If you are looking for something in kibana which can give you information similar to curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v', then you can go to "Monitoring-> Indices"  which will list out all the index with there stat's(document count, data size, index rate etc).

If you don't have the x-pack installed then you have to use the "Discover" tab where you can see the list of all the index from the drop down, also the _type and all the available fields in the index.